# JQuery Self in Data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
function Class() {
    var self = this;
    var $div = $('<div/>');
    $div.data('obj',self);

    this.get = function() {
        return $div;
    }
}

var x = new Class();
var $y = x.get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t8ZTW/2/

The problem is that I store the object "self" data using jQuery's .data() function, but I cannot seem to access it later.  What is going wrong?

EDIT:

The following is the code I should actually be asking about:

```
function Class() {
    var self = this;
    var $div = $('<div/>');
    $div.data('obj',self);

    var sample = "S";

    this.get = function() {
        return $div;
    }
}

var x = new Class();
var $y = x.get();

alert($y.data('obj').sample); // <-- This returns 'undefined'
```

Comment: Your fiddle has two syntax errors and the jQuery library isn't loaded. Can you please fix and edit your answer? Also, you'll probably get an answer faster if you include the code in your question.

Comment: After you fix the obvious problems you'll notice that you never set a `$div` property so `x.get()` doesn't return your `$div`.

Comment: I apologize; I was trying to abstract my code - because it's quite a bit more congested than this.  I believe I fixed the missing () and the missing this.  I am unsure if jsfiddle is reporting errors anymore, but my Firebug doesn't seem to.

Comment: OK, so now with those syntax problems fixed what is the actual problem you are asking about? Please show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my original post - my revised code is in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$div` isn't a property of `this` -- rather, it's simply a variable in an accessible scope:

```
this.get = function() {
    return $div; // remove `this.`
}
```

Despite similar names and values, these is no relation between the `$div` variables:

```
function Class() {
    var $div = $('<div/>');
    this.$div = $('<div/>');
}
```

If you want a variable to be a property of the object, you have to define it on `this`:

```
function Class() {
    var self = this;
    var $div = $('<div/>');
    $div.data('obj',self);

    this.sample = "S"; // `this.sample` rather than `var sample`

    this.get = function() {
        return $div;
    }
}

var x = new Class();
var $y = x.get();

alert($y.data('obj').sample); // "S"
```

Comment: How can I return the reference to the entire object, though... I believe my only option is to use jQuery's .data function - otherwise it wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: @sdasdadas Which object are you referring to? Cause, you have 2 references to the instance of `Class` -- `x` and `$y.data('obj')` both return to the same object. Now, to retrieve `sample`, it needs to be defined as `this.sample`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Class()` constructor (as called by `new Class()`) creates a new object that has one method, `.get()` and *no* other properties. When you call the `.get()` method on your `x` object the method tries to return `this.$div` but there is no property called `$div`. The `.get()` method does, however, have access to the local variables `self` and `$div`, so try changing it to say:

```
return $div;
```

EDIT for your edit:

`$y.data('obj')` should retrieve a reference to your object, but then you do the same thing I was talking about above and try to access a property of the object - `.sample` - which has not been defined. You need to change the definition of `sample` to be:

```
this.sample = "S";
```

So then it actually is a property of the object and can be accessed with `$y.data('obj').sample` *or* with the much simpler `x.sample` (given that `x` is a direct reference to the object and doesn't need to go through all the `.data()` nonsense).